# React router v6 not rendering anything on "/" route. Rest all route is working fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm recently started using React Router v6 but facing weird behavior. Nothing is rendering on the "/" route rest all the routes are working perfectly fine. I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.

But if I add a redirection logic in the "/" route then it is working I mean it's redirecting to some other route. but I want to show a component in the "/" route also.

**My Code**

**package.json**
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavigationRoutes from './routes';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <NavigationRoutes />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**NavigationRoutes.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';
import ProtectedRoute from './privateRoute';
import { appRoutes, routesWithoutLayout } from './routes';

const NavigationRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    {routesWithoutLayout.map(({ protected: _protected, id, path, element }) =>
      _protected ? (
        <Route key={id} path='/' element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path={path} element={element} />
        </Route>
      ) : (
        <Route key={id} path={path} element={element} />
      )
    )}
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
      {appRoutes.map(({ protected: _protected, id, path, element }) =>
        _protected ? (
          <Route key={id} path='/' element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path={path} element={element} />
          </Route>
        ) : (
          <Route key={id} path={path} element={element} />
        )
      )}
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<p>Page not found</p>} />
  </Routes>
);

export default NavigationRoutes;
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('SOME-TOKEN');

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return children || <Outlet />;
  }
  return <Navigate replace to='/login' />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Route.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Home from '../pages/home';
import Login from '../pages/login';
import ProtectedPage from '../pages/protected';
import Signup from '../pages/signup';

export const appRoutes = [
  {
    id: 'SOME_UNIQUE_STRING',
    path: '/protected',
    protected: true, // if true then login required to access the route
    element: <ProtectedPage />,
  },
  {
    id: 'Home',
    path: '/',
    protected: false, // if true then login required to access the route
    element: <Home />,
  },
];

export const routesWithoutLayout = [
  {
    id: 'Signup',
    path: '/signup',
    protected: true, // if true then login required to access the route
    element: <Signup />,
  },
  {
    id: 'Login',
    path: '/login',
    protected: false, // if true then login required to access the route
    element: <Login />,
  },
];
```

**Layout.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <div>
    Layout
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

But if I mention the `/` route explicitly in Route then it will work. But in my view, it's redundant and also illogical as I'm maintaining a separate file for routing.

**Working Code for NavigationRoute.js (index file in route folder)**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';
import Home from '../pages/home';
import ProtectedRoute from './privateRoute';
import { appRoutes, routesWithoutLayout } from './routes';

const NavigationRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
     // redundant and also illogical 
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    </Route>
    {routesWithoutLayout.map(({ protected: _protected, id, path, element }) =>
      _protected ? (
        <Route key={id} path='/' element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path={path} element={element} />
        </Route>
      ) : (
        <Route key={id} path={path} element={element} />
      )
    )}
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
      {appRoutes.map(({ protected: _protected, id, path, element }) =>
        _protected ? (
          <Route key={id} path='/' element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path={path} element={element} />
          </Route>
        ) : (
          <Route key={id} path={path} element={element} />
        )
      )}
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<p>Page not found</p>} />
  </Routes>
);

export default NavigationRoutes;
```

**My folder structure**

[image: Folder Structure]

Thanks for the help

Comment: The routing code is quite convoluted. Which `"/"` path are you referring not working?

Comment: home route path i.e. ```localhost:3000/``` where <Home /> component should render.

Comment: in index.js file `import NavigationRoutes from './routes';` is the problem, it should be `import NavigationRoutes from './NavigationRoutes.js';` ;

Comment: no, I'm importing ```NavigationRoutes``` from the index file of the routes folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are over-complicating the routes a bit, specifically what you are wanting to be a layout route.

## Using a layout route and `Outlet` components

The layout routes should omit the `path` prop. This allows the nested `Route` components to render their `element` prop into the layout route component's `Outlet` (*i.e. both `Layout` and `ProtectedRoute` component's `Outlet`*).

Example:

```
const NavigationRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    {routesWithoutLayout.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) =>
      protected ? (
        <Route key={id} element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path={path} element={element} />
        </Route>
      ) : (
        <Route key={id} path={path} element={element} />
      )
    )}
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      {appRoutes.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) =>
        protected ? (
          <Route key={id} element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path={path} element={element} />
          </Route>
        ) : (
          <Route key={id} path={path} element={element} />
        )
      )}
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<p>Page not found</p>} />
  </Routes>
);
```

Or conditionally render a route with the `PrivateRoute` or `Outlet` as the `element`.

```
const NavigationRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    {routesWithoutLayout.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) => {
      const LayoutWrapper = protected ? ProtectedRoute : Outlet;
      return (
        <Route key={id} element={<LayoutWrapper />}>
          <Route path={path} element={element} />
        </Route>
      );
    })}
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      {appRoutes.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) => {
        const LayoutWrapper = protected ? ProtectedRoute : Outlet;
        return (
          <Route key={id} element={<LayoutWrapper />}>
            <Route path={path} element={element} />
          </Route>
        );
      })}
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<p>Page not found</p>} />
  </Routes>
);
```

## Using wrapper components and the `children` prop

The code could also be simplified by rendering the `ProtectedRoute` as a wrapper component instead of a layout route component. This utilizes the `children` prop instead of using the `Outlet` component.

Example:

```
const NavigationRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    {routesWithoutLayout.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) => {
      const Wrapper = protected ? ProtectedRoute : React.Fragment;
      return (
        <Route
          key={id}
          path={path}
          element={<Wrapper>{element}</Wrapper>}
        />
      );
    })}
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      {appRoutes.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) => {
        const Wrapper = protected ? ProtectedRoute : React.Fragment;
        return (
          <Route
            key={id}
            path={path}
            element={<Wrapper>{element}</Wrapper>}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<p>Page not found</p>} />
  </Routes>
);
```

Reduce further by moving the `protected` condition into the `ProtectedRoute` and handle the conditional rendering of the `element`.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, protected }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('SOME-TOKEN');

  if (!protected || isAuthenticated) {
    return children || <Outlet />;
  }
  return <Navigate replace to='/login' />;
};
```

...

```
const NavigationRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    {routesWithoutLayout.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) => (
      <Route
        key={id}
        path={path}
        element={<ProtectedRoute {...{ protected }}>{element}</ProtectedRoute>}
      />
    ))}
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      {appRoutes.map(({ protected, id, path, element }) => (
        <Route
          key={id}
          path={path}
          element={<ProtectedRoute {...{ protected }}>{element}</ProtectedRoute>}
        />
      ))}
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<p>Page not found</p>} />
  </Routes>
);
```

## Use an improved routes configuration object and the `useRoutes` hook

Resturcture the routes config to more closely match what/how you want to render the routes and use the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes) hook

Example:

```
export const appRoutes = [
  {
    // routes with Layout
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        // protected routes
        element: <ProtectedRoute />,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/protected',
            element: <ProtectedPage />,
          },
          ... other protected routes inside Layout
        ],
      },
      // unprotected routes
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Home />,
      },
      ... other unprotected routes inside Layout
    ],
  },
  // routes w/o Layout
  {
    // protected routes
    element: <ProtectedRoute />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/signup',
        element: <Signup />,
      },
      ... other protected routes outside Layout
    ],
  },
  // unprotected routes
  {
    path: '/login',
    element: <Login />,
  },
  ... other unprotected routes outside Layout
];
```

NavigationRoutes

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';

const NavigationRoutes = () => {
  const routes = useRoutes(appRoutes);
  return routes;
};

export default NavigationRoutes;
```

Comment: Wow.. is that that simple. I have tried the useRoutes solution and it works well. Thanks for all this variety of answers. I believe I need to look at the documentation again to understand how this object structure is working. Anyway thanks again, man. you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `NavigationRoutes` in your `index.js` file but you have not imported it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to mention it in question as I've other redux stuff there. Now  I've updated the question